# Transitions during page navigation in phonegap android app

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova

I am developing a phonegap android application using jquery Mobile that consists three html pages. I want to include transitions during navigation from one page to another.
For navigation between pages i have used

```
window.location = "abc.html";
```

Each page consists some dynamic data that loads on page initialization.
I have tried **data-transition="slide"**. But there isn't any effect.
How can i include slide transition for page navigation in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.mobile.changePage('abc.html', { transition : 'slide'});
```

Comment: thnx Ved bt this trick isn't working for me...i have tried this already.Any other solution?

Comment: <a href="abc.htm"  data-role="none"  data-transition="slide">
OR 
You can add all pages in one page and call using page id :
<a href="#abc"  data-role="none"  data-transition="slide">

Answer (score 0):

```
function change_page(page){

    $.mobile.changePage( page, { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });

}
```

Call this function:`change_page('#load_page');` OR `change_page('mypage.html');`